# Searching for and parsing out specific text parts within the values of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-searching

I'm working on a CASE expression that I need to have in order to search for, and parse out, specific text values.

Sometimes the relevant column will contain a *person's name*, and sometimes it will contain a *city* AND a *two digit state abbreviation*. I need to search in the column and determine if it contains a city and state, and if it does then I need to parse out the two character state abbreviation. For example, the column will contain `'[PHOENIX, AZ.]'`.

I currently have:

```
 CASE
      WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(cu.address),2) IN('AL','AK','AZ', etc...) 
      THEN RIGHT(RTRIM(cu.address),2)
```

The problem I'm running into, is that sometimes there's a `'.'` (period) either before or after the two digit state abbreviation.

Rather than write a bunch of different code that would account for every type of anomaly, I need something that will account for everything.

Comment: Please update your question to include sample data (in the form of insert statements) that represent the scenarios you are trying to parse.  We also need the expected results from a successful query against that data.

Comment: Can we rely on the fact that an existing comma always represents an address that will have a state code after it?  What comes after the state code?

Comment: The state code should always be last, with the exception of a period or a blank space.  A comma isn't always present, but there should always at least be a space between the city and state

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply use `replace` to eliminate the period before the `rtrim`?  `CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(replace(@Address,'.','')),2) IN('AL','AK','AZ') THEN RIGHT(RTRIM(replace(@Address,'.','')),2) end as addr`

Comment: Splendid!  For extra credit, how would I then parse out the city portion (PHOENIX)?